# Global Variable Alternatives in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC 4 / C# / .NET website that someone else set up, that I'm managing. I have a HomeController and ArticleController. I am looking for a way to define the name of an article in one place and use it all over. Specifically though, in Index.cshtml (called via HomeController) and all the articles (Article_1, Article_2, etc.) called via ArticleController.cs.

My original plan was to define a global variable (I used [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368129/c-sharp-global-variables) to set it up):

**HomeController:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyStie.Controllers
{
    public class Globals
    {
        public static article_1_title = "This will show up all over the place";
    }
    public class HomeController : Controller //This is basically the same as ArticleCont.
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            retrurn View();
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
<div>@{Write(Globals.story_1_title)}</div>
```

This didn't work though, so if you think globals are the way to go, let me know what I'm doing wrong here.

But, upon reading [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/672543/How-to-use-global-variable-in-Csharp), which basically says reliance on global variables is not good for C#, I'm wondering if globals are the way to go. If you agree with that, How should I accomplish this?

Comment: Why not use `<div>@Globals.story_1_title</div>`?

Comment: What does "that didn't work" mean?  My guess is your problem is this mysterious "Write" method you have there...

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am misinterpreting what you want, but why not use your web.config file to hold the static information that you need and reference it from there.

**Web.config**

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
       <add key="ArticleTitle" value="This will show up everywhere"/>
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**Controller**

```
 public class HomeController : Controller //This is basically the same as ArticleCont.
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["ArticleTitle"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ArticleTitle"];
            retrurn View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1, but this almost seems like a complete 'duh' concept. When I read the question I was thinking, 'uh, why is this not a configuration setting?'

Comment: @JoelEtherton - I felt the same way and almost didn't post as an answer thinking I wasn't reading it correctly.  However, I know I have sometimes forgotten the "easier" way of doing things :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var abc= '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["abc"]';
```