# Accessing a list through file?

Tags: c#

I'm pretty expereinced in java and can't seem to figure out how to use a global variable in a sense.

How would I access the list foodSource in the on selectedIndexChanged method? I want to have it so when an item is selected, its price is displayed in a separate label.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        initFood();
    }

    private void initFood()
    {
        var foodSource = new List<Food>();

        foodSource.Add(new Food { name = "Pizza", price = 10 });
        foodSource.Add(new Food { name = "Burger", price = 15 });
        foodSource.Add(new Food { name = "Chips", price = 5 });
        this.menu.DataSource = foodSource;
        menu.DisplayMember = "name";
    }

    private void menu_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you make it a private class level field just like you would have in java?

Comment: No such thing as a global variable in C#. The best you can get is a [static member of a public class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368129/c-sharp-global-variables).

Comment: @user3042332 Have you tried to debug menu_SelectedIndexChanged and look what is it getting as sender and e? sender is boxed in object it is consider to be your Food object.

Answer (score 4):

Your `List<Food>()` is used as the datasource of the control named `menu`.
So you can always retrieve the same list accessing the datasource as a `List<Food>`

```
private void menu_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Food> source = menu.DataSource as List<Food>;
    source.foo();
}
```

No need to have 'global variables' around.

A more in depth explanation: When you write `var foodSource = new List<Food>();` you are allocating a memory area in the heap to keep your list data. The reference to this area is assigned to a local variable named *foodSource* and finally the *DataSource* property of the control is assigned to the same reference. However, being the *foodSource* a local variable created on the stack it is discarded when the code exits from the *initFood* method, but the memory area on the heap is still in use because the DataSource property keeps a reference to the area. When your code reaches the *SelectedIndexChanged* event handler you just need to use the [as keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) to have a valid reference to the same memory area where the original `List<Food>` was stored.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to have foodSource be a member of the `Form1` class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<Food> foodSource;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        initFood();
    }

    private void initFood()
    {
        this.foodSource = new List<Food>();

        this.foodSource.Add(new Food { name = "Pizza", price = 10 });
        this.foodSource.Add(new Food { name = "Burger", price = 15 });
        this.foodSource.Add(new Food { name = "Chips", price = 5 });
        this.menu.DataSource = foodSource;
        menu.DisplayMember = "name";
    }
}
```

Then you can access it from your method.

```
    private void menu_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.foodSource.foo();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast a `sender` object which should be exactly that guy who holds your data source. But from your example it is not clear WHY do you need to access that list? Doesn't `EventArgs e` ship all the necessary data?