# Define members of static List outside of method

Tags: c#, winforms, list, class

I am having class with `public static List` which looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static List<Tuple<Ogranicenja, string>> defaultValues = new List<Tuple<Ogranicenja, string>>();
//Here i want to add item
}
```

I would add new item to list easy if i am creating class with constructor inside it:

```
public MyClass()
{
    defaultValues.Add(new Tuple<Ogranicenja, string>(Ogranicenja.Dnevno, "TEST");
}
```

BUT i do not want it like that. I want that list to be just like database but inside code with about 20 rows and so it is accessible to every class so how can i accomplish that.

It is not same as [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368129/c-sharp-global-variables) question since i know how to do `public static int test = 1` but how to the same thing with list which is typeOf `Tuple` and need to have multple items.

Comment: Look at edit. Since it it normal to do `public static int test = 1` why isn't something like that possible with list?

Comment: Yea at the time i create it.

Comment: It is not normal to have a static mutable state, like `public static int` or `public static List`. Moreover, public fields violate Microsoft design guidelines. In your case it should be `private static readonly IReadOnlyCollection<>` and then a public static property to access it from outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add values to a collection at the time you declare it, like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static List<Tuple<Ogranicenja, string>> defaultValues
        = new List<Tuple<Ogranicenja, string>>
            {
                Tuple.Create(new Ogranicenja(...), "string_one"),
                Tuple.Create(new Ogranicenja(...), "string_two")
            };
}
```

Comment: It is working. Was never into lists so this confused me. Thanks