# Making a global variable int

Tags: c#, sql-server, int

When we login I want to use the `EmployeeId` in *different windows*. What is a good solution to do this?

So that after the login, the `EmployeeId` is a `public int` for *all windows*.

We use SQL Server for the login.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Global Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368129/c-sharp-global-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming the application is WinForms or WPF then:

```
class Program
{
    public static int EmployeeId {get;set;}

}

class OtherWindow
{
    void Function()
    {
       int employeeId = Program.EmployeeId;

    }
}
```

If your app is a web server or other 'multi-user' system, then you will need to find a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Why not? If you want to see `EmployeeId` as if it's a *global variable* you can implement a routine like below. But ensure `EmployeeId` being *thread safe*:

```
namespace MyNameSpace {
  ...
  public static class MyEnvironmentVariables {
    // Lazy<int> - let EmployerId be thread safe (and lazy)
    private static Lazy<int> GetEmployeeId = new Lazy<int>(() => {
      //TODO: implement it
      return ObtainEmployeeIdFromDataBase();
    });

    public static int EmployeeId {
      get {
        return GetEmployeeId.Value;
      }
    }
  }
```

then with a help of `using static` you can see it as if you have a *global variable*:

```
  // static: we don't want to mention pesky MyEnvironmentVariables
  using static MyNameSpace.MyEnvironmentVariables;

  ...
  public class MyDifferentWindow {
    ...
    public void MyMethod() {
      // we can use EmployerId as if it's a global variable
      int id = EmployeeId;
      ...
```