# Access a variable from one method in another

Tags: c#

I know this has been asked before but I still can't figure it out and those answers don't help. I need to know how to do exactly what the code below shows but successfully.

```
public void ProgressBar_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int somevariable;
}

public void ProgressBar_MouseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int anothervariable = somevariable;
}
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368129/c-sharp-global-variables

Comment: That's not possible, simple as that. You either need to use a class-level field/property or pass the variable as a parameter which you cannot do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your method,

```cs
public void ProgressBar_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int somevariable;
}
```

Imagine the method as a black box with an input and an output - you can put data in and receive data out, but you don't know what's happening on the inside of the box.

Therefore, when you create `int someVariable` inside the method, nothing else in your code can 'see' this.

To get around this issue, you should use variables inside your class, like so:

```cs
public class Program
{
    private int somevariable;

    public void ProgressBar_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Operate on somevariable
    }

    public void ProgressBar_MouseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int anothervariable = somevariable;
    }
}
```

If we go back to the black box analogy, now imagine that it has a peephole that it can only look out of. Therefore, your methods (black box) can look out into the class and 'see' the `int somevariable`, but other objects still cannot look inside the method.

You could also pass `somevariable` between methods, however by the looks of it you are responding to UI events, and therefore can't do this easily.

Answer (score 3):

```
private int _somevariable;
public void ProgressBar_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //changing _somevarible
    }

public void ProgressBar_MouseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         int anothervariable = _somevariable;
    }
```

Local varibles exists only during method execution.

Answer (score 0):

So you have 2 different events that are called from 2 different actions. So the basic answer would be you can't pass a value from one action to another directly. For doing this you would need to declare that "_somevariable" as a global variable, but in C# we don't have that so the next best solution would be to use static class and static variables.

Action 1: Mouse Down call's ProgressBar_MouseDown

Action 2: Mouse UP call's ProgressBar_MouseUp

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
    public static int somevariable { get; set; }
}

public void ProgressBar_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //changing _somevarible
    //somevarible=set your value here
}

public void ProgressBar_MouseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //int anothervariable = somevariable;
    //here you should be able to access the somevariable
}
```

Comment: Static means that the value will be shared between all instances. Maybe in this particular case this is not a problem, but why not use a class-level field?

Comment: A class-level field will work (if the application is simple and all events are from the same class) but let's suppose the user needs to solve a business problem for a complex application. There is a high possibility that both the events may not be in the same class or we may have additional constraints so it's better to store the data as a static.