# How to change a class variable?

Tags: c#, class, variables, scope

I have a class in a very basic C# console game (text adventure) that I would like to modify a variable elsewhere in the code. I understand that C# does not allow global variables, but that is essentially what I am looking for.

I am a beginner at programming. I am stumped and I've been unable to find an answer to this question. It's really a question of scope that I'm after; what variables can "talk" to each other. I'll include a simple example below.

All of these fields in the class will
 be modified elsewhere within various methods.

```
class Player        
{
    public int health = 100;
    public string armor = "none";
    public string gun = "none";
    public int money = 1000;
}

    public static void AddMoney()
{
    var NewPlayer = new Player();
    NewPlayer.money += 1500;
}
```

So I want to basically know what is expected of me to do if global variables aren't a thing in C#.

Comment: Well, you showed that you are indeed able to change the public (aka global) variables using `NewPlayer.money`. So what's the problem? Are you looking for [static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) members implementation?

Comment: Field variables shouldn't be public.  Make them properties.

Comment: I'd recommend you read up about class constructors

Comment: In your own words, what is a class? What is an object? What is your existing understanding of how this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways of updating instance variables in C#: Using [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) or setters like in Java or instance methods. Following code shows you a few of those.

Ultimately, what you want to do is pass a reference to the instance of the player to different methods and let them use the properties/methods to update the instance variables:

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var p1 = new Player();

            p1.Health = 5000;
            p1.Armor = "Helmet";
            p1.AddMoney(200);

            Console.WriteLine($"Health: { p1.Health }");

            var enemy = new Enemy();

            enemy.Shoot(p1);

            Console.WriteLine($"Health after being shot: {p1.Health}");
        }
    }

    class Player
    {
        private string armor;
        private int money;

        public int Health { get; set; }

        public string Armor
        {
            get => armor;
            set
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Updating armor.");
                armor = value;
            }
        }

        public int Money { get; private set; }

        public void AddMoney(int money)
        {
            // More complex logic here, example: synchronization.
            this.money = money;
        }
    }

    class Enemy
    {
        public void Shoot(Player p)
        {
            p.Health -= 500;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the object-oriented way of doing things. As for global variables in the sense of application-wide variables, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368129/how-to-use-global-variables-in-c).

You can also make the `Player` a [singleton](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton). This is more a design choice than actual C# stuff. I'm not going to go into singleton pattern here. If you search singletons and their pros and cons, you will get an earful of that :)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: you could make `Player` a `static` class, which would probably behave how you want, but doing so is ill-advised as it limits you to a single player object and can't easily be unit tested, amongst other problems. See [When to use static classes in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241339/when-to-use-static-classes-in-c-sharp).

You have to understand that you `Player` is a class. Think of it as a blueprint for how a `Player` object should look. I usually go to a car analogy for this: you buy two Toyota Priuses. Identical in every way. You take one to a spray shop and have a design painted on it. Has the other Prius changed? No. It's the same with `var player1 = new Player(); var player2 = new Player();` - they are both of type "Player", but they are not the same player.

Now consider your AddMoney method:

```
public static void AddMoney()
{
    var NewPlayer = new Player();
    NewPlayer.money += 1500;
}
```

You're creating a player that only exists within the `AddMoney` method. Once outside, it effectively doesn't exist anymore (stuff isn't deleted from memory immediately, but [garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130382/understanding-garbage-collection-in-net) isn't a topic you should be concerned with just yet).

Since `Player` is a `class`, it's a [*reference type*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c), which means that passing it to a method will pass a reference to the same object in memory. This means that we can change the object in `AddMoney` and it will be reflected in the caller. Note that we can't *replace* the object - for that you would need the [`ref` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186891/why-use-the-ref-keyword-when-passing-an-object) (but that's another topic too).

```
public static void AddMoney(Player player)
{
    player.money += 1500;
}
```

Example:

```
var player = new Player();
player.money = 8500;
Console.WriteLine(player.money); // 8 500
AddMoney(player);
Console.WriteLine(player.money); // 10 000
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/AVOWT8830)

Alternatively, if you want to create a player, you could create a factory method:

```
public static Player CreatePlayer()
{
    return new Player
    {
        money = 1500
    };
}
```