# Global members in .Net

Tags: .net, global-variables, clr, global, member

Are there global members in .Net?

Every time I google I can find nothing about the global members, but while reading the **CLR via C#** I come across the following:

> This causes ILDasm.exe to run, loading the Program.exe assembly. To see the metadata in a nice,
>   human-readable form, select the View/MetaInfo/Show! menu item (or press CTRL+M). This causes the
>   following information to appear:

```
===========================================================
ScopeName : Program.exe
MVID : {CA73FFE8-0D42-4610-A8D3-9276195C35AA}
===========================================================
Global functions
-------------------------------------------------------
Global fields
-------------------------------------------------------
Global MemberRefs
-------------------------------------------------------
TypeDef #1 (02000002)
-------------------------------------------------------
 TypDefName: Program (02000002)
 Flags : [Public] [AutoLayout] [Class] [Sealed] [AnsiClass] 
etc...
```

So, since the **Global functions**, the **Global fields** and the **Global MemberRefs** are not parts of any type, does that mean that there are global members in .Net?

Comment: Technically no, there isn't a concept of Globals... Static would be the closest solution. [See here](https://www.arclab.com/en/kb/csharp/global-variables-fields-functions-static-class.html#targetText=A%20global%20variable%20is%20a,or%20class%20within%20the%20namespace.) or [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368129/how-to-use-global-variables-in-c)

Comment: @Anu6is, thank you for your comment. But your comment does not make clear what the Global functions, the Global fields and the Global MemberRefs mean in the result produced by the `ILDasm.exe`.

Comment: Global members are members of the special `<Module>` class (ECMA-335, Partition II, Section 10.8 - Global fields and methods). C# doesn't support global members but other languages might.

Comment: @BrianReichle, can I access the `<Module>` class from C# somehow?

Comment: The referenced section of the spec seems to suggest that you can reference the global members through reflection, though I have never tried.