# How to transfer a value from public(that i got from another form) to other functions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, public

I want to get the value from Übergabe_Darkmode that could be the value = 1. And i want to use it in the function: Einzelspieler_Load

```
namespace Schiffe_versenken
{
    public partial class Einzelspieler : Form
    {       
        public Einzelspieler(int Übergabe_Darkmode)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.MaximizeBox = false; 
            this.MinimizeBox = false; 
        }

        private void Einzelspieler_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(Übergabe_Darkmode == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hui");
            }
```

Comment: Store it in a class field. `this.Übergabe_Darkmode = Übergabe_Darkmode;` with an appropriate declaration.

Comment: can u explain what a class field is ?

Comment: [Fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields).

Comment: Check this post :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368129/how-to-use-global-variables-in-c

Comment: @Jannis Class fields is very basic knowledge. You should learn it in every Toutorial before Chapter 10.

Comment: @XAMT No Global Variables please. Avoid it as long as you can.

Comment: @XAMT but I need one to get the value from the other form .. Or is there another way ?

Comment: @Christopher I think I knew how but I dont know the perfect definition for the word, bc english isnt my home language ..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
namespace Schiffe_versenken
{
  public partial class Einzelspieler : Form
  {       
    public Einzelspieler(int Übergabe_Darkmode)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MaximizeBox = false; 
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        darkmode = Übergabe_Darkmode;
    }

    private int darkmode { get; set; }

    private void Einzelspieler_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(darkmode == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hui");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The main aspect of the form Tag property is handling of user variable when the instantiating it.

So, you can use it as well.