# How can I create a variable inside a function that can be used in all other functions?

Tags: c#

I am trying to assign a variable that can be used in any other function, **inside** a function.
It is gonna be the path for my program, and it's important.
I don't know how to set/get `global`s.
Thank you for any help!
This might be a duplicate, but I'm not sure what post to go on, or either what post does work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Global Variables in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368129/how-to-use-global-variables-in-c)

Comment: No, sorry. I don't work with those other .cs files. I work in one single file, with probably a reference inside it.

Comment: With one single file, I don't see why you need to do anything other than declare a class member at the top of your class and assign it in your function?

Comment: Can you give pseudo-code example? I can't understand why you can't achieve this by simple declaration.

Comment: `public void createJAVM(string path, bool logging, string logFileNameWithoutExtension = "bootlog.log")
        {
            public static string JAVMPath = path;`

It doesn't work. I'm sorry for being such a noob in C#.

Comment: you cannot declare a class member inside a method. just *declare* the string `JAVMPath` at the top of the class (outside the function) and *assign* the string in the function

Comment: Oh, that might be correct.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

There are no global variables in C#. At least not in the "traditional" sense. In C# evertthing happens inside classes, so the closest thing is a `public static` field in a class. And, really - it's just a global variable in disguise.

Comment: I tried using that, but I really don't know how to set them up.

Comment: Also, I need to put a variable inside the variable, so technically I would make a function argument completely global.

Comment: @Ceyhun - sounds like you need a tutorial on the basics of C#.