# Can't access global variable in C# web application

Tags: c#, webforms, global-variables

I Wrote the below lines of code in my Data Access Layer(DAL).

```
private static int _myvar;
public static int Myvar
{
    get { return _myvar; }
    set { _myvar = value; }
}
```

I provided all necessary namespaces in CodeBehind and Created DAL object there.
Still I could not access that proprety. Showing "Qualify it with a type name instead".
Can Someone Please help with it?

Comment: A static variable is not a global variable. IMO, that is a very good thing.

Comment: I would not store anything critical in a static variable for application state

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368129/how-to-use-global-variables-in-c