# The amount of killedzombies does not increase / count, what is the reason?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, testing, 2d

I am making a game in unity, i am trying to increase the killedzombies after a zombie got destroyed but it doesn't work.this is written at the console:

```
1
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
zombieScript:TakeDamage (int) (at Assets/zombieScript.cs:49)
zombieScript:OnTriggerEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collider2D) (at Assets/zombieScript.cs:31)
```

My code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class zombieScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float snelheid; // velocity
    Transform speler; // player
    public int leven; // health
    public playerScript playerScript;
    public int killedZombies;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        speler = FindObjectOfType<playerScript>().transform;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, speler.position, snelheid * Time.deltaTime );

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "bullet")
        {
            TakeDamage(other.GetComponent<bulletScript>().damage);
        }

        if(other.tag == "Player")
        {

            SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
            
        }
    }

    void TakeDamage(int damageAmount)
    {
        leven -= damageAmount;
        if(leven <= 0) // if (health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            killedZombies++;
            Debug.Log(killedZombies);

            if(killedZombies == 10)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
            }

            
        }
    }

}
```

I asked chatgpt but it told me that there were no problems with the code.

Comment: You need to create a global object to save `killedZombies`, or just save it in your `playerScript` (assume you have only one)

Comment: is this on every zombie? if so so is killedzombies, and will always be zero, therefore  you  add 1 to zero, and destroy so all the others remain at zero.  Thus why chatgpt is not the answer to everything

Comment: this is on every zombie. how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Each time a zombie gets hit you are increasing the killedzombie variable in that same zombie's script, and then destroying it. You're basically adding 1 to 0 and then deleting the script.

There are two simple solutions, as suggested in the comments.

1. In the zombie script, have a public object and connect it to your player. Now make a `KilledZombiesCounter` variable in the player script. Whenever a zombie gets hit, it will access the `KilledZombiesCounter` in the player's script and add 1 to it. then destroy the zombie. Easy and clean.
2. Make a 'global' variable. Now do the exact same thing as the other solution except instead of accessing the player's script you will simply increase the global variable. More information about global variables is available here [How to use global variables in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368129/how-to-use-global-variables-in-c)

Hope I was helpful, cheers ;)