# Getting open xlsx Filename from Process ID

Tags: c#, excel, file

I'm trying to build a form that allows a user to select a previously opened Excel instance.

From there, I want to extract out the name of the `.xlsx` file associated with that opened instance.

I suspect I'll have to use COM to get it out of there, but I haven't found a way to do it.

The code I'm thinking is as follows:

```
Process[] openApplications = Process.GetProcessesByName("excel");

foreach(Process p in openApplications)
{
    ///Find the associated .xlsx path and file
    ///...Maybe from the handle id?
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916711/get-the-current-workbook-object-in-c-sharp

Comment: Let me know if the above solves your issue so that I can mark this question as a duplicate :D

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `ActiveWorkbook` property.
Please refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174744(v=office.11).aspx).

```
        try
        {
            Process[] openApplications = Process.GetProcessesByName("excel");
            int proLen = openApplications.Length;
            if (proLen == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The process does NOT exist or has exited...");
                return 0;
            }

            foreach(Process p in openApplications)
             {
             //validate p for null/nothing
             //get the name of the workbook using
             //Use p.ActiveWorkbook.Name to get the file name.
             }        
            return 1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Do each of the Process objects within openApplications have a .ActiveWorkbook.Name in them?  I'm not seeing that.

Comment: I'm using VS2017 - this answer does not seem to work. p.ActiveWorkbook.Name is not a valid selection

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll have to add a reference to the [Microsoft Excel Object Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx) to get an instance of the running MS Excel application:

```
var application = (Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
```

Then you can get the full path of the file via [ActiveWorkbook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.activeworkbook.aspx) and [FullName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.fullname(v=office.15).aspx) properties.

```
Console.WriteLine(application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName);
```

And if you have more than one instance of MS Excel opened, you can iterate over them via [Workbooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.workbooks(v=office.15).aspx) property:

```
foreach (Workbook workbook in application.Workbooks)
{
    // do something with workbook.FullName
}
```

Comment: I get an exception when I do the var application = ...

Also, what do I do if there are multiple open workbooks?  I'm trying to allow the user to select the active one...

Comment: @TimC, that's not a very informative description of what's happening. Make sure you use object library of the version that corresponds to the target version of MS Excel; try searching the net for the problem described in the exception message; if it doesn't help, you can ask a new question, but please do include all the relevant information, [some tips](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).