# VBA add-in subscription list for App level events

Tags: vba, events

I am creating an excel Add-In (`.xlam`) that needs to selectively respond to workbook/worksheet events, in all open workbooks (user may have multiple workbooks open). I dont want to go down the road of pasting code into other open workbook's `ThisWorkbook` modules.

I would like the user to be able to select whether the Add-In will respond to the active workbook's events.

What would be the most appropriate solution to achieve this?

Currently, I am thinking of a solution that looks like this:

Enable the Add-In to listen to application level events via a `cls_AppEvents` class (`cls_AppEvents` is instantiated on `Workbook_open()`).

When user clicks button, add the `ActiveWorkbook.Name` to an array of stings. When user clicks button again, remove the 'ActiveWorkbook.Name` from the array.(This would need to be a dynamic array - is there a better option?)

When application-level `TableUpdate` (for example) event fires, check the array of workbook names to see if it contains the Workbook's name where the event originated. If so, call whatever function.

Comment: there are globals for thisaddin.  `.Application.ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: For better performance, you could use a Collection instead of an Array and store references to the worksheet objects instead of their name.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav could you elaborate?

Comment: Have the add-in inspect a `CustomProperty` of the workbook. If the property is present and set to enable events, have the add-in act on the events for that workbook, if it is absent or unset, don't act on events for that workbook. Have the add-in offer functionality for adding/configuring the `CustomProperty` for any existing or new workbook.

Comment: you need to read about it, this was the 1st result on google http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916711/get-the-current-workbook-object-in-c-sharp