# c # interop Can you tell which file excel is running using excel?

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I want to quit Excel, which is opening certain files when there are a lot of excel running.

I know how to run Excel excel and know how to terminate the process, but I do not know how to exit excel that reads certain files.

I wonder if there is a way to shut down excel (or office) running a particular file through an interop or some other way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the current Workbook Object in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916711/get-the-current-workbook-object-in-c-sharp)

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/060000d8-a899-49bf-a965-0576dee958d4/how-to-get-active-application?forum=exceldev .

Comment: for many excell process this one give the guidlines on how to loop throught all process. If you have issue with this solution please [edit] and [mcve] in your question

Answer (score 0):

Excel is a red herring here, what you're actually looking to do is discover which running process has locked a particular file on disk. It doesn't matter that it's an excel file in particular. This is a fairly common requirement and is well covered in other SO answers such as:

[How do I find out which process is locking a file using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317071/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-using-net)

Answer (score 0):

**This is what you want:**

```
 foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL"))
    {
        process.Kill();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To close a specific/particular excel file

```
private static void KillSpecificExcelFileProcess(string excelFileName)
{
    var processes = from p in Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
                    select p;

    foreach (var process in processes)
    {
        if (process.MainWindowTitle == excelFileName.Substring(0, excelFileName.IndexOf(".")) + " - Excel" )
            process.Kill();
    }
}
```

Pass the File name in the method call and in result the specific process will be close/kill